# guidance on how to conduct a logistic regression with three categorical dependent variables

Tags: regression, logistic

I am also looking for guidance on how to conduct a logistic regression with three categorical dependent variables. My two independent variables are dichotomous and experimentally manipulated. Of the three dependent variables: two are dichotomous, one has four categories. None of the categories in the IVs or DVs are ordered.

I'm in the process of exploring a 5-way logit (loglinear) approach following Wuensch's description on his teaching website. I did a screening run using hierarchical loglinear analysis (ignoring the fact that some variables are DVs), followed by a loglinear analysis of a model that include only effects involving the DVs (i.e., IV-only effects not included from the outset). The rationale Wuensch gives is that our random assignment of respondents to IVs ensures the effects of the IV-only terms are zero or near-zero, which makes logical sense and is what I found.

Not sure this is the correct way, but it's all I've found to date. Would really appreciate comments on this approach! especially around the issue of excluding effects that are IV-only.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you looked into ordinal and multinomial logistic regression?

Comment: Thanks -- I took your suggestion and looked into that and, yes, I'm looking for help on the multivariate version of multinomial regression (since I want to analyze 3 outcome variables). Any good refs you can think of? I have looked at (Agresti 2007) on multivariate multinomial logit C9-10 but it looks like it's about repeated response data -- unless that includes multiple different variables measured t the same time, instead of the same variables measured over multiple times?